# JPA Exception Transaction is still active

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, transactions

I am developing an android application with appengine backend.In one of my endpoint method, I query datastore to retrive entities as below:

```
try {
            mgr.getTransaction().begin();
            bookList = (List<Book>) q.getResultList();
            mgr.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        mgr.close();
    }
```

I am getting following exception while trying to query from client app:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: Transaction is still active. You     should always close your transactions correctly using commit() or rollback().
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Transaction is still active. You should always close your transactions correctly using commit() or rollback().
at org.datanucleus.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForJDOException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:195)
at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:157)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastoreEntityManager.close(DatastoreEntityManager.java:62)
at com.example.bookemon.BookEndpoint.searchBook(BookEndpoint.java:414)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)

at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Transaction is still active. You should always close your transactions correctly using commit() or rollback().
FailedObject:org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager@859b59
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.close(JDOPersistenceManager.java:277)
at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:153)
... 34 more
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: Are you sure that there is not another transaction started but not committed or rolled back in some other piece of code executed prior to this one during the same request?

Comment: Was a Throwable thrown instead of Exception? Bothered looking at any exception that was thrown? or the log?

Comment: @DavidLevesque there was a little mistake in writing my code.I have edited the code and I am still getting error with this code.

Comment: @pratim You didn't answer my question... also I think the code was better with the `rollback`, not sure why you removed it.

Comment: in the `finally` block you can change the code to: `if (!mgr.isActive()) mgr.close;` But that doesn't solve your problem, because you have a transaction open and not committed or rolled back yet. Please add the `entity manager` initialization and settings to the post.

Comment: I agree, can you please post the rest of the context for this code? How are you initializing everything etc... Also please make sure your code is in line with the recommended configuration/pattern [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/transactions.html).